# Issue with Facelets page regarding embeded scripts code in a 'code' element

Tags: html, rendering, facelets

Very confusing question I know, and it's a bit of a gobstopper for me!

I am trying to display bash script code in a Facelets page so that user can copy the scripts code from browser. This code is placed in a `code` element as posted below. But requesting the page gives me error(s) related to what I think is the cause (in bold). I have tried replacing the `{`, `}`, & `-` characters with the html replacements and I still get errors. Perhaps this is not allowed?

#!/bin/bash
        #Author: Yucca Nel http://thejarbar.org
        #Will restart system
        #Modify these variables as needed...
        tempWork=/tmp/work
        defaultStartScript=/etc/init.d/rc.local
        defaultMaven=3.0.4
        locBin=/usr/local/bin
        mavenUsrLib=/usr/lib/maven
        
        sudo mkdir -p $mavenUsrLib
        mkdir -p $HOME/.m2
        
        read -p "Please [Enter] full path name of your local startup script ($defaultStartScript is the default). Please
        make sure on this before providing a value by consulting documentation for your system:" locStartScript
        **locStartScript=${locStartScript:-$defaultStartScript}**
        
        read -p "Please [Enter] Maven Version ($defaultMaven is default):" mavenVersion
        **mavenVersion=${mavenVersion:-$defaultMaven}**
        
        
        if [ ! -f $locStartScript ]
        then
        echo "The file you provided could not be found. Remember to include the full path and try again. Exiting in 7 secs..."
        sleep 7
        exit 1
        fi
        
        mkdir -p /$tempWork
        cd /$tempWork
        
        wget http://mirrors.powertech.no/www.apache.org/dist//maven/binaries/apache-maven-$mavenVersion-bin.tar.gz
        tar -zxvf ./

        

        *#Move it to a more logical location

        sudo mv -f ./apache-maven-$mavenVersion $mavenUsrLib/

        

        #If you have Maven on Windows and use VirtualBox, you can set up the maven to be a virtualbox shared folder.

        #The name must match the name used below (ignore if irrelevant to you).

        

        

        if [ -f /sbin/mount.vboxsf ]

        then

        sudo /sbin/umount $HOME/.m2

        sudo /sbin/umount $mavenUsrLib

        sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf .m2 $HOME/.m2

        sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf maven $mavenUsrLib

        fi

        

        if mountpoint -q $HOME/.m2 &&  mountpoint -q $mavenUsrLib

        then

        #Add it to the start script to automate process...

        if ! grep "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf .m2 $HOME/.m2" $locStartScript

        then

        echo "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf .m2 $HOME/.m2" | sudo tee -a $locStartScript

        fi

        

        if ! grep "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf maven $mavenUsrLib" $locStartScript

        then

        echo "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf maven $mavenUsrLib" | sudo tee -a $locStartScript

        fi

        echo "exit 0" | sudo tee -a $locStartScript

        sudo chmod +x $locStartScript

        

        #Create a mount and unmount script file...

        rm -rf $tempWork/*
        echo '#!/bin/bash' > $tempWork/maven-mount.sh
        echo "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf .m2 $HOME/.m2" >> $tempWork/maven-mount.sh
        echo "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf maven $mavenUsrLib" >> $tempWork/maven-mount.sh
        echo "echo 'mounted maven'" >> $tempWork/maven-mount.sh
        echo "exit 0" >> $tempWork/maven-mount.sh
        
        echo '#!/bin/bash' > $tempWork/maven-umount.sh
        echo "sudo umount $HOME/.m2" >> $tempWork/netbeans-umount.sh
        echo "sudo umount $mavenUsrLib" >> $tempWork/netbeans-umount.sh
        echo "echo 'unmounted maven'" >> $tempWork/maven-mount.sh
        echo 'exit 0' >> $tempWork/maven-umount.sh
        
        #Script for mounting ALL VirtualBox shared solders....
        #If there isn't one create one...
        if [ ! -f $locBin/mount-all-from-host.sh ]
        then
        echo '#!/bin/bash' > $tempWork/mount-all-from-host.sh
        echo "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf .m2 $HOME/.m2" | sudo tee -a $tempWork/mount-all-from-host.sh
        echo "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf maven $mavenUsrLib" | sudo tee -a $tempWork/mount-all-from-host.sh
        echo "exit 0" | sudo tee -a $tempWork/mount-all-from-host.sh
        
        #Otherwise if there is one, but no mount, add one...
        elif ! grep "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf .m2 $HOME/.m2" $locBin/mount-all-from-host.sh
        then
        sudo sed -ie '$d' $locBin/mount-all-from-host.sh
        echo "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf .m2 $HOME/.m2" | sudo tee -a $locBin/mount-all-from-host.sh
        echo "exit 0" | sudo tee -a $locBin/mount-all-from-host.sh
        
        elif ! grep "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf maven $mavenUsrLib" $locBin/mount-all-from-host.sh
        then
        sudo sed -ie '$d' $locBin/mount-all-from-host.sh
        echo "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf maven $mavenUsrLib" | sudo tee -a $locBin/mount-all-from-host.sh
        echo "exit 0" | sudo tee -a $locBin/mount-all-from-host.sh
        
        fi
        
        #Script for unmounting ALL VirtualBox shared folders...
        #If there isn't one create one...
        if [ ! -f $locBin/umount-all-from-host.sh ]
        then
        echo '#!/bin/bash' > $tempWork/umount-all-from-host.sh
        echo "sudo umount -a -t vboxsf" | sudo tee -a $tempWork/umount-all-from-host.sh
        echo "echo 'unmounted all VirtualBox shared folders'" | sudo tee -a $tempWork/umount-all-from-host.sh
        echo "exit 0" | sudo tee -a $tempWork/umount-all-from-host.sh
        fi
        
        sudo chmod +x $tempWork/

        *sudo mv -f $tempWork/*.sh $locBin/
        rm -rf $tempWork
        fi
        
        sudo ln -f -s $mavenUsrLib/apache-maven-$mavenVersion/bin/* /usr/bin/
        sudo rm -rf $tempWork
        sudo /sbin/reboot
        
        exit 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:  `mavenVersion=$<h:outputText value="{mavenVersion:-$defaultMaven}"/><br/>`